# Do Math.max and Math.min change the value they are applied to?

Tags: java

I've been reading some code that one of my lecturers set and he has written something like "Let us set a maximum and minimum for a value."

Then he writes (and I'm paraphrasing values here)

```
int x = 5;
x = Math.min(x, 0);
x = Math.max(x, 10);
```

Then he carries on with his code as if x is still equal to 5 whereas when I run this code through my computer the max and min functions always change the value of x to 0 and then 10.

**Does this sound like a mistake on his part? Should he have reverted x before carrying on? Or does this function work in some other way depending on circumstances that it does actually set a maximum and minimum value without changing the original variable?**

Comment: This is why assignment is an advanced subject. Though no one seems to have told anyone (much).

Answer (score 5):

You are right; he probably meant this:

```
int x = 5;
x = Math.max(x, 0);
x = Math.min(x, 10);
```

which keeps x between 0 and 10.

Answer (score 2):

It is a mistake on his part. When you assign a variable with `=` it sets it to that value.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It is a mistake on his part.